# Making a variable I can manipulate further

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to jQuery and need to perform some transformations on the following working code:

```
   jQuery('#vari_1').click(function() {
    var selected = [];
         jQuery('#cartsnitch')
         .addClass('new')
         .html(jQuery('#vari_1')
              .find('input[type="radio"]:checked')
              .val())
              .fadeIn('5000');
    })
```

The code returns the value of a radio button clicked in a tab id of #vari_1.

The problem is I then need to replace hyphens of the radio button value with spaces (duck-egg-blue to duck egg blue) and prepend an h2 heading. Chaining these appears to break my code.

I instead tried the below to make it into a variable so I can work with that on a new line, but couldn't get it to work. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
   jQuery('#vari_1').click(function() {
    var selected = [];
    var cart1 = jQuery('#cartsnitch')
         .addClass('new')
         .html(jQuery('#vari_1')
              .find('input[type="radio"]:checked')
              .val())
              .fadeIn('5000');
    var cart2 = ('<h2>My heading</h2>') + cart1;
    return cart2;
    })
```

It's driving me nuts! Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't see your **.html()** closed with ')'

Comment: To be honest you've got a lot of problems here. You've misunderstood chaining somewhat. `val()` does return a value (even though you're not returning that value to anything) but not if you continue to chain after it, i.e. with `.fadeIn()`. And your attempt to append a `h2` doesn't append it TO anything; you've assumed you can just do `+` after it; I'm not sure where you've read that.

Comment: Would be easier to help if you provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue with relevant HTML markup and better explain your expected behaviour. BTW, you said `on the following working code` but for sure it doesn't work so quite hard to figure out what are you expecting here?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a closing bracket after html. I just need to wrap my working code in a variable and add something to the start of it, can someone show me the correct syntax to do this? I understand I have problems here, hence why I'm asking. Just trying to get a better understanding of it.  Thank you.

Comment: There isn't a single answer to your question because there are multiple problems. Seriously, the best thing you can do is spend a little time with the jQuery docs and/or tutorials. For example, learn how to DOM-script elements - `('<h2>My heading</h2>') + cart1;` is pseudo-jQuery and it seems you've assumed that will just work. Check your error console - you'll have at least few errors showing up that you can learn from.

Comment: Thanks Utkanos, hoped it would be as simple as 'you need to add this syntax to make it work' but I guess I need to learn jQuery completely before I dare ask for help with it on SE! Thanks anyway sir.

Comment: SO can seem daunting - even unfriendly - when people don't answer your question but the reasons are normally that there's just too much wrong with a question/code to provide a straight-up answer. Sometimes we have no choice but to say "head to the docs". If you get stuck with something specific later, though, we'll be here for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sure can seem daunting Utkanos, I'm yet to get a straight answer to a question after being a member for a good few years. All I seem to attract is ambiguity and politician style question dodging!

Anyway due to lack of a hint other than Ashkay's syntax error spot (not in my code sorry), I fixed it as such:

```
jQuery('#vari_1').click(function() {
    var selected = [];
    jQuery('#cartsnitch').addClass('new')
.html(jQuery('#vari_1')
.find('input[type="radio"]:checked')
.val().replace("-"," "))
.prepend('<div class="mystyle"><small>My Label:</small><br />')
.append('</div>')
.fadeIn('5000');
```

})

val().replace() prepend() and append() were all I was after.

Thanks for the reassurance anyway!